Unable to install Pods in a new Project after updating to latest Xcode 16 (macOS Sequoia)
After navigating to project directory and typing the command 'pod init', the following error is showing in the terminal:
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
Command
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod init

Report

What did you do?

What did you expect to happen?

What happened instead?


Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.5.19
        Host : macOS 15.0 (24A335)
       Xcode : 16.0 (16A242d)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)
Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib
Repositories : cocoapods - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ da55fa335942b4a2e81c666525751a7f14f999f6

               trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Plugins
cocoapods-clean       : 0.0.1
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

Error
RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup` from attributes: `{"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", "exceptions"=>["364918B02CA149C300EA094B"], "path"=>"PodTest", "sourceTree"=>"<group>"}`
If this ISA was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:359:in `rescue in object_with_uuid'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:349:in `object_with_uuid'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:290:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `configure_with_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:213:in `initialize_from_file'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%60PBXGroup%60+attempted+to+initialize+an+object+with+unknown+ISA+%60PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup%60+from+attributes%3A+%60%7B%22isa%22%3D%3E%22PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup%22%2C+%22exceptions%22%3D%3E%5B%22364918B02CA149C300EA094B%22%5D%2C+%22path%22%3D%3E%22PodTest%22%2C+%22sourceTree%22%3D%3E%22%3Cgroup%3E%22%7D%60%0AIf+this+ISA+was+generated+by+Xcode+please+file+an+issue%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCocoaPods%2FXcodeproj%2Fissues%2Fnew&type=Issues
If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new
Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
Don't forget to anonymize any private data!
Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
I am unable to create a new Pod Project Xcworkspace after updating to latest version of macOS and Xcode

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.


Convert the project folder to Group

Remove following

minimizedProjectReferenceProxies = 1;
preferredProjectObjectVersion = 77;


Change this line :

objectVersion = 77; to objectVersion = 56


Save and run pod init


For detail:
https://youtu.be/DfxEByfscfk?si=Pnql7yzK4Qq9X0qd
this solves the problem.

Update CocoaPods:
brew update
brew install cocoapods
pod repo update
pod --version


Try this step by step it will be resolved.

Close XCode
Go to your project folder remove Pods & Podfile.lock
Right Click on YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj Show Package Contents then open project.pbxproj
Replace every PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup with PBXGroup
Search for objectVersion should be like that objectVersion = 56; if not replace by 56
Pod install


You can use xcode to convert to group instead of "Replace every PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup with PBXGroup".

Steps to Fix:

Convert to Group:


In Xcode, right-click on your project folder and choose Convert to Group from the menu.


Modify Project Settings:


Right-click on your projectname.xcodeproj file and select Show Package Contents.
Open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor.
Remove the following lines:
minimizedProjectReferenceProxies = 1;
preferredProjectObjectVersion = 77;
Update the version number by changing:
Change objectVersion = 77; to objectVersion = 56;

If you have tests also convert them to group 
made a video for this fix check it out  https://youtu.be/WUvW3in1QVs
